# ADF add ActivityRunID to Sink table

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a sink table that I would like to populate with the ActivityRunID of the Copy Data iteration within the Until loop

[image]

I understand that I cannot map ActivityRunID within the Copy Data task until that task is completed. My Until looks like this:

[image]

Is there an easy way to populate my sink with the RunID once the Copy Data task has finished? I was thinking of populating the sink with a dummy GUID then using a Lookup task to populate it in a subsequent task

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the `Lookup` activity just to pull your dummy GUID.

Alternatively, you can generate a GUID using data factory dynamic expressions and store it in a variable using Set Variable activity. And use the variable in later activities directly.

[image]

[image]

If you want to use the `copy data` activity **RunID**, create a stored procedure to update the value in the sink with the input parameter and pass the parameter of activity RunID from the stored procedure activity.

Parameter value: `@activity('Copy data1').ActivityRunId`

Comment: Hey @Brian, had it solved your problem else you can share more details so I can troubleshoot?